# Maven ignoring local repository location changes

Tags: java, maven, repository, settings, quarkus

Im trying to change the location of Mavens local repository, but it didnt work for me so far.
Im currently doing the tutorial of quarkus: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started

I changed the localRepository setting in the settings.xml to
 `<localRepository>D:\Zubehoer\Maven\repository</localRepository>`
and also copied that settings.xml to the .m2 folder in my user home.
When I do `mvn compile quarkus:dev` as shown in linked tutorial the dependencys get downloaded to the default repository instead of the location I changed the local repository to.

Lastly the pom of the project:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>getting-started</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.5.2.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.5.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Edit:
Relevenat image of  maven debug output[image: maven debug output]

Comment: which IDE are you using ?

Comment: Eclipse, but I didnt use the eclipse-maven. Everything I have done was done with the standalone maven.

Comment: Do you see the same issue with `mvn package -DskipTests`?

Comment: @AlexeyLoubyansky same, with ```mvn package -Dskiptests```

Comment: In that case, it looks like a Maven config issue. Have you tried building non-Quarkus project with these settings?

Comment: Maven probably isn't looking at the right settings file. Can you start it with the debug option (`-X`) and check the first few lines of the output? Can you also check you haven't got a *duplicate* `localRepository` tag in the corresponding settings file?

Comment: @MichaelBerry I added an image of the debug output in my post. I checked both settings.xml files and both only contained 1 localRepository property. The value of those as said in the original post is ```<localRepository>D:\Zubehoer\Maven\repository</localRepository>```

Comment: @AlexeyLoubyansky its the same for another non quarkus project

Comment: @goldarm5 Further sanity check, does `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository -q -DforceStdout` definitely print out the wrong local repository?

Comment: @MichaelBerry that prints C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository

Comment: @goldarm5 That's bizarre. Last thing I can think of to check is that your `localRepository` tag is definitely at the top level (well just under `<settings>`) and not inside another tag. You could temporarily just try changing the file contents to "<settings><localRepository>D:\Zubehoer\Maven\repository</localRepository></settings>" to see if it picks it up.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I think Ive got the problem, and as one would exspect its a pretty simple one in the end I think. I didnt exactly realize that by default the localRepository property is inside a comment, and the view in WordPad doesnt really highlight this. I just ctrl + f searched for localRepos and changed the value inside ```<localRepository></localRepository>``` . Makes sense it doesnt work if thats inside a comment...

Comment: @goldarm5 That definitely gets a ‍♂️ emoji...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So by default the `<localRepository></localRepository>` property of mavens settings.xml is inside a comment:
`<!-- localRepository** | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts. | | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository> -->`

As I only changed the value of the localRepository property, but did not move the property outside of the comment it didnt work.